# Class-based view "has no attribute .as_view()" error

Tags: python, django

I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-the-django-rest-framework--cms-19786), trying to make an API for my `Products` table.

Here's my .views/API/apitest.py view:

```
from my_app.views.API.serializers import ProductSerializer
from my_app.models import Product
from rest_framework import generics

class APITest(generics.ListAPIView):
    model=Product
    serializer_class=ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

The urls.py entry:

```
url(r'^API/products/$', views.API.apitest.as_view(), name='apitest')
```

That line gives an error: `'module' object has no attribute 'as_view'`. I'm just trying to create a simple example for the moment, so there's no need for decorators. What causes this error? I'm using Django 1.9.2.

Comment: you can change it views.APITest.as_view()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

apitest is the module, you need to use `as_view` on the class

```
url(r'^API/products/$', views.API.apitest.APITest.as_view(), name='apitest')
```

Although it may be better to look into your imports

```
from myapp.views.API.apitest import APITest
url(r'^API/products/$', APITest.as_view(), name='apitest')
```