# Using Django UserPassesTestMixin with LoginRequiredMixin to go to an authorized URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm trying to write a mixin that will protect views by first checking if someone is logged in and then if they have been onboarded. It seems to work, by blocking views it's attached to, but it the URLjust goes to a 403 forbidden. Any ideas on how to get it to go to the named url?

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class OnboardedMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    """
    a custom mixin that checks to see if the user has been onboarded yet
    """

    def test_func(self):
        if self.request.user.onboarded and self.request.user.is_active:
            return True

    def get_login_url(self):
        return redirect('onboarding',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than taking this approach, maybe its best to use a decorator instead. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def my_login_required(function):
    def wrapper(obj, request, *args, **kw):
        decorated_view_func = login_required(request)
        if not decorated_view_func.user.is_authenticated:
            return decorated_view_func(request)  # restricts without login and sends to signin view

        if request.user.onboarded and request.user.is_active:
               return function(obj, request, *args, **kw)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/onboarding/")

    return wrapper
```

And use this decorator in desired views:

```
 class SomeView(DetailView):
    ...

    @my_login_requried
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(SomeView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. Why use this method instead of a UserPassesTestMixin? I'm not seeing an obvious reason outside the simplicity that you proposed. And... well, it is simpler. Thoughts?

Comment: That doesn't seemt o work with Generic Class Based Views. It triggers a .as_view() error on each view that uses it

Comment: @DaveMerwin I have tested with Generic Class Based Views, for example TemplateView, and its working. Maybe your error is occurring for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396930/class-based-view-has-no-attribute-as-view-error . I have suggested this idea, because it is a cleaner and simpler solution than overriding 2 mix-ins.